# Как в Glide добавить json body request и sertificate для получения картинки?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, glide

Для получения картинки с сервера мне необходимо прикрепить хедеры, метод запроса (POST), тело запроса (`JSONObject` с несколькими полями ключ-значение) и сертификат.

Всё хорошо работает в ручной установке картинок в `ImageView`, но сейчас требуется использовать библиотеку Glide, в которую неизвестно как добавить все эти данные.

Так выглядит мой запрос на сервер, в котором `Request` - это класс-контейнер, который хранит в себе хедеры, `HttpMethod` и тело запроса (`JSONObject`):

```
private String executeRequest(Request request) {
    return executeRequest(buildHttpRequest(request));
}

private String executeRequest(HttpRequestBase httpRequest) {

    String response = "";

    String url = httpRequest.getURI().toString();

    boolean useCerificates = url.contains(HOST_SUBSTRING);

    try{

        URL URLObject = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection;

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) URLObject.openConnection();
        if(connection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
            if (useCerificates)
            ((HttpsURLConnection)connection)
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLContext().getSocketFactory());
            else {
                SSLContext sslContext;
                sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                sslContext.init(null, null, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                ((HttpsURLConnection)connection)
                        .setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
            }
        }

        connection.setRequestMethod(httpRequest.getMethod());

        Header[] requestHeaders = httpRequest.getAllHeaders();
        for (Header requestHeader : requestHeaders)
            connection.setRequestProperty(requestHeader.getName(), requestHeader.getValue());


        if (connection.getRequestMethod().equals("POST")) {
            String requestBody = getRequestBody(httpRequest);
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStreamWriter.write(requestBody);
            outputStreamWriter.flush();
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        }


        int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();

        if (statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            response = getResponseString(connection.getInputStream(),"utf-8");
        else{
            response = getResponseString(connection.getErrorStream(),"utf-8");
        }

        connection.disconnect();

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В `Glide` к запросу можно добавить заголовки, используя [`GlideUrl`](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/load/model/GlideUrl.html):

```
GlideUrl glideUrl = new GlideUrl("url", new LazyHeaders.Builder()
        .addHeader("key1", "value1")
        .addHeader("key1", "value2")
        .build());

Glide.with(context)
        .load(glideUrl)
        .into(targetImageView);
```

Установить SSL-сертификат так просто не получится, но вообще это возможно, используя `OkHttp`. Подробнее можно почитать в статье:

[Glide Module Example: Accepting Self-Signed HTTPS Certificates](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-module-example-accepting-self-signed-https-certificates)